# how to recive the response of a post method send with guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle

I am calling an api with guzzle and Sending some data and that api return me  some data that i want to recive them and show them so here is my code :

```
$requestapi = $client->post('http:url/api/v1/transaction/Verify', [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
        'body' => '{
        "tn":"1905463527",
        }'
    ]);
```

now when i dd the $requestapi its now showing me the result that verify api returns and just showing me the 200 response .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GuzzleHttp\Client::post` method returns `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response` object.
You can simply use `getBody` method to access the response body.

```
$response = $client->post(...);
$contents = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: yes right thanks for the right answer but how can i access the items of getbody ??

Comment: for example can i use contents->name ?? if we consider server sending a name for me ??

Comment: @Farshad it is depending on response format. For application/json content type you can create an array from the response string `$array = json_decode($contents, true)` and access `name` property through array access `$array['name']`